# How can i handle ACTION_SHUTDOWN event on HTC desire for Power off option

Tags: android

I have registered broadcast to receive `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` , its working properly on all devices

However on HTC desire it's not getting called in case of Power off.
In case of Restart, the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is getting triggered.

What Action do I need to check to handle the same case for 'Power off' option?
I want to do same operations what i did for restart option.

Comment: I have tried to clarify your question a bit by formatting it into more then just a long sentence. Could you review and see if it still says what you wanted it to say?

Comment: yeah .. thanks I am not able to get ACTION_SHUTDOWN on power off option click on HTC desire...

Comment: Are you sure you need this intent? WHat do you need it for? As all apps will be paused, you do not normally need to handle this?

Comment: Yeah ...I am handling this event to send the Logout request to the server if the deivce is restarting or shutting down ... I got the answer on HTC desire We ll get the intent Action in case of power off "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" we need to handle this ...

Comment: I doubt this is the way to go (what if there is no connection during shutdown? there could be a chance of that). But I don't know your complete app obviously. If that intent you mentioned answers your question, please provide it as an answer below, and accept it: it'll help future users

Comment: Using android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF intent action it resolve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

When you Power Off phone goes in sleep mode, not real shutdown. So ACTION_SHUTDOWN doesn't broadcasted.

Answer (score 1):

Your device shutdown receiver should register for both these intents:

1. "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"
2. "com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" (Some posts have wrongly stated "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF")

Comment: `com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF` how to add this in manifest??